# Can I use a Node NuGet package to install gulp through the package manager console and other npm packages?

Tags: .net, npm, msbuild, gulp, nuget

I have created an executable that runs on a visual studio build to auto-compile sass. The trouble is that there are backend developers that don't have node installed and consequently aren't building sass on every build. To fix this issue, I am hoping there is a NuGet that I can install that will allow me to have Node installed in the project so that I can install npm packages.

I have tried multiple of these Node NuGet packages but because there is almost no documentation regarding any of these NuGets, I am left in the dark on how to use them.

Am I incorrect to assume that I should just be able to run node commands through the Package Manager Console? Is there a specific path I have to be at in order to run the node commands?

I have tried the two NuGets below with no success and if someone could provide some instructions on how I am supposed to use these and whether I am supposed to be able to do npm commands from within the package manager console that would be very helpful.

- Node.js 5.3.0: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Node.js/
- Node.js Environment Integration 1.0.2: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NodeEnv/

Answer (score 0):

The first package (Node.js) doesn't contain npm.

The second one does contain but a very ancient one.
It is possible to run it using  "node.exe npm\bin\npm-cli.js"

This package install NPM and Node.js : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npm/
Although an old one (Current is 3.10.9: https://libraries.io/npm/npm/) , so you need to update running "npm update".